# LogicException node save via ResourceBase post()

Tags: 8

When i try to create a node via rest api (8.4) I keep getting

> LogicException: The controller result claims to be providing relevant cache metadata, but leaked metadata was detected. Please ensure you are not rendering content too early. Returned object class: Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse

The node is created but my app recieves an error.

the end point code is as follows

```
namespace Drupal\transactions\Plugin\rest\resource;
use Drupal\rest\Plugin\ResourceBase;
use Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse;
use Drupal\node\Entity\Node;



/**
 * Provides a Transactions Resource
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "transactions",
 *   label = @Translation("Stripe Transactions"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/api/v1/transactions",
 *     "create" = "/api/v1/transactions",
 *   }
 * )
 */

class TransactionsResource extends ResourceBase{

  public function get() {
    return new ResourceResponse("Implement REST State GET!");
  }

  /**
   * Responds to entity POST requests.
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   */
  public function post($payload) {
    $recipient = Node::create([
      'type' => 'recipient',
      'field_firstname'=>"name3",
      'field_lastname'=>"name2",
      'field_mobile'=>"3128371973193",
      'field_city'=>"london",
      'field_country_to'=>"UK"
    ]);
    $recipient->save(); //error occurs here

  $response = new ResourceResponse(['nid', $recipient->id()]);
  $response->addCacheableDependency($recipient);

    return $response;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Responses to a POST request should not be cached. Use an uncacheable response like [ModifiedResourceResponse](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21rest%21src%21ModifiedResourceResponse.php/class/ModifiedResourceResponse/8.4.x):

```
  $response = new ModifiedResourceResponse(['nid', $recipient->id()]);
```